# "Data truncated for column 'password' at row 1"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, php7

Весь интернет посмотрел ничего но узнал что можно изменить длину столбцов так как md5 воспринимает 28+ символов пожалуйста подскажите как это сделать
Вот код:

```
<?php
require "index.html";
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST["login"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST["password"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = md5($password);
$mysql = new mysqli("site", "root", "", "test");
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `reg`(`login`, `password`) VALUES('$login', '$password')");
$result = $mysql->query;
if(!$result){ 
    var_dump($mysql->error);
};

$mysql->close();
?>
```

Спасибо большое кто поможет

Comment: длина столбцов изменяется в БД

Comment: Алексей Шиманский после изменения ничего не случилось тоже самое ошибка и в бд не отправляются данные

Comment: какую длину поставил?

Comment: 128 на всякий случай или это слишком?

Comment: Приведите ПОЛНЫЙ текст сообщения, полученного от MySQL. Приведите полный CREATE TABLE для таблицы. Соберите текст запроса в переменной, а не сразу в `$mysql->query`, и покажите его.

Comment: *md5 воспринимает 28+ символов* Функция MD5() в PHP возвращает строку длиной 32 байта. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.md5.php

Comment: ALTER COLUMN password VARCHAR(32);

Comment: И вообще зачем md5? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Я уже догадался что нужно было указать password не INT а VARCHAR все заработало